# Error: A value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"

Tags: c++, struct, char

For some reason, the indicated code below comes up with an error reading, " A value of type "const char ** (only supposed to be one asterisk of course)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char" ". I found this very weird, as fname and lname seemed to be no different, yet they did not come up with such errors as I would expect. I tried making char phone into char** phone too, but to no success. Could someone let me know what the problem is and how to fix it?

```
 struct Name {

    char fname[15];
    char lname[15];

};

struct Info {

    int grade;
    char phone[15];

};

struct Mark {

    int math;
    int sci;
    int eng;

};

struct Student {

    Name n;
    Info i;
    Mark m;

};

int main()
{

Student class_list[MAX_CLASS_SIZE] = {
    // Errors here          V V V V V V V 
    {"Bob", "Smith"}, {11, "519-688-5168"}, {88, 75, 78}
};

}
```

Comment: That's because you're using C strings in C++. Don't do that. Use `std::string`.

Comment: You need another set of braces, but really you need some constructors.

Comment: The latter of those is the actual problem; the former good advice (but would still leave you with an error without the latter applied). [See it live](https://ideone.com/mN4S6B).

Comment: `MAX_CLASS_SIZE` is not defined

Comment: @NikosC. do you mean use string instead of char[15] with phone? I tried that and it comes up with the same error

Answer (score 0):

This

```
{"Bob", "Smith"}, {11, "519-688-5168"}, {88, 75, 78}
```

is what you'd use if you were defining and initializing a *single* `Student` object:

```
Student student = {
    {"Bob", "Smith"}, {11, "519-688-5168"}, {88, 75, 78}
};
```

However, you are trying to initialize an *array* of `Student` objects, so each element needs to be within braces:

```
Student class_list[MAX_CLASS_SIZE] = {
    { {"Bob", "Smith"}, {11, "519-688-5168"}, {88, 75, 78} }
//  1 2                 3                     4
};
```

1: `Student` object initializer.
2: `Name` object initializer.
3: `Info` object initializer.
4: `Mark` object initializer.

With that being said, you should avoid using C strings. Use `std::string` instead:

```
#include <string>

struct Name {
    std::string fname;
    std::string lname;
};

struct Info {
    int grade;
    std::string phone;
};

struct Mark {
    int math;
    int sci;
    int eng;
};

struct Student {
    Name n;
    Info i;
    Mark m;
};

int main()
{
    Student class_list[MAX_CLASS_SIZE] = {
        { {"Bob", "Smith"}, {11, "519-688-5168"}, {88, 75, 78} }
    };
}
```